# Eclipse GEF drag & drop distinguish file extension

Tags: eclipse, events, drag-and-drop, eclipse-gef

I am implementing a EMF+GEF Editor and also want to support Drag & Drop from the Package/Project Explorer.
So far I've made nice progress following this tutorial: https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-dnd/GEF-dnd.html

However, now I'm stuck here:
I need to create different objects based on the file-type.
For example I want to create an object of type A when I drop an XML file and an object of type B when I drop a TXT file.

I can access the filename on the `handleDrop()` event, but the problem is that at `createTargetRequest()`, when I set the factory-type, the information about the extension is not available.

i.e. the function`isComponentXML()`, that accesses `((String[])getCurrentEvent().data)[0]` leads to an exception.

```
protected Request createTargetRequest() {
    CreateRequest request = new CreateRequest();
    if(isComponentXML()){
        request.setFactory(componentfactory);
    } else if (isControlFile()){
        request.setFactory(filefactory);
    }
}
```

Can somebody suggest a way where I can access the filename or the tree-object during `createTargetRequest()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did create my own solution now, although it is probably not the best one and I am still hoping for somebody to come up with something else and share it here. However, in case somebody else has this problem and doesn't know how to go on about it:

I have basically created my own `Request` and `TargetDropListener` and then added it to the `Policies` of my `EditPart`. The logic for determination of the correct object (according to file extension) is added to `getCommand(...)` in the `Policy`. For people who are still unaware of what I have been doing, there is a step by step guide below.

---

**Step 1**: Create your own request object:

```java
public class FileTransferRequest extends Request implements DropRequest {

    public static final String TYPE = "FILE_TRANSFER"; // for comparison 

    private Point location;  // stores where the new Object should be displayed
    private String filepath; // this is the data bit...

    public FileTransferRequest() {
        setType(TYPE); // set the type of the request so we can recognise it later
    }

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
    @Override public Point getLocation() { return this.location; }
    public void setLocation(Point location) { this.location = location; }
    public void setFilePath(String filepath){ this.filepath = filepath; }
    public String getFilePath(){ return this.filepath; }
}
```

**Step 2**: Create a TargetDropListener

```java
public class ResourceTransferDropTargetListener extends AbstractTransferDropTargetListener{

    public ResourceTransferDropTargetListener(EditPartViewer viewer, Transfer xfer) {
        super(viewer, xfer);
    }

    public ResourceTransferDropTargetListener(EditPartViewer viewer) {
          super(viewer, FileTransfer.getInstance());
    }

    @Override public boolean isEnabled(DropTargetEvent event) {
        return true; // maybe you want some smarter code here
    }

    // creates a new Request, will be called by getTargetRequest() if necessary
    @Override protected Request createTargetRequest() {
        return new FileTransferRequest();
    }

    // this routine is called repeatedly and sets the x/y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    @Override protected void updateTargetRequest() {
        ((FileTransferRequest)getTargetRequest()).setLocation(getDropLocation());
    }

    // prevent moving, we want to copy the file... 
    @Override protected void handleDragOver() {
        getCurrentEvent().detail = DND.DROP_COPY;
        super.handleDragOver();
    }

    // called on drop. THIS IS WHERE WE GET ACCESS TO THE FILE NAME (for the first time)
    @Override protected void handleDrop() {
        ((FileTransferRequest)getTargetRequest()).setFilePath(getFilepath());
        super.handleDrop();
    }

    // a helper for the function above... returns only one element (for multiple selections you will have to change something here and above)
    private String getFilepath(){
        return ((String[])getCurrentEvent().data)[0];

    }
}
```

**Step 3**: Register Handler in your `MyEditor.java`

```java
....

@Override
protected void initializeGraphicalViewer() {
    super.initializeGraphicalViewer();
    getGraphicalViewer().setContents(/* whatever you are displaying */);

    // add the TransferDropTargetListener to the Editor
    getGraphicalViewer().addDropTargetListener(new
        ResourceTransferDropTargetListener(getGraphicalViewer()));
}

.....
```

**Step 4**: This is the important part. 
The TargetDropListener will try to find an EditPolicy that implements a policy, corresponding to the `YourRequest.TYPE`. Therefore we need to either create a new `EditPolicy` or extend an old one. 
(I have chosen to extend an existing one because I want to keep it simple and not mess with many files...)

***Step 4a***: Add the request type to the EditPolicy. In case it 'gets asked' what it can handle, it will return its EditPart

```java
public class MyXYLayoutPolicy extends XYLayoutEditPolicy {

    // This function will be called to find out what types it can handle. 
    // We need to return an EditPart to signal that we can. 
    // FileTransferRequest.TYPE serves as the identifier
    @Override public EditPart getTargetEditPart(Request request) {
        if(request.getType().equals(FileTransferRequest.TYPE)){
            return getHost();
        }
        // if the previous didn't trigger, return what it would have done normally
        return super.getTargetEditPart(request); 
    }

    ....
}
```

***Step 4b***: After returning the correct EditPart, `getCommand(...)` will be called, so we need to return a Command...
I'll leave the Command implementation open for your own research, but if you are looking for help:
[here](http://www.vainolo.com/2011/07/07/creating-a-gef-editor-%E2%80%93-part-7-moving-elements-and-direct-editing/) is a good place to find information. (also for other GEF things)
Hint: extend `Command` and implement `execute()` and `undo()`!

```java
public class MyXYLayoutPolicy extends XYLayoutEditPolicy {

    ....

    @Override public Command getCommand(Request request) {
        if(request.getType().equals(FileTransferRequest.TYPE)){ // for file DND
            return handleFileTransferRequest(request);
        }
        return super.getCommand(request);
    }

    private Command handleFileTransferRequest(Request request){
        FileTransferRequest req = (FileTransferRequest) request;
        if(req.getFilePath().endsWith(".xml")){ // XML file
            System.out.println("XML");
            XMLCreateCommand command = new XMLCreateCommand();
            command.setLocation(req.getLocation());
            command.setParent((Graph)(getHost().getModel())); 

            Component c = GraphFactory.eINSTANCE.createComponent();
            c.setName(req.getFilePath);
            command.setComponent(c); 
            return command;
        } else if(((FileTransferRequest) request).getFilePath().endsWith(".txt")){ 
            System.out.println("TXT");
            TXTCreateCommand command = new TXTCreateCommand();
            command.setLocation(req.getLocation());
            command.setParent((Graph)(getHost().getModel())); 

            TXTFile f = GraphFactory.eINSTANCE.createTXTFile();
            f.setName(req.getFilePath());

            command.setFile(f);
            return command;
        } else {
            return null; // a FileTransferRequest, but not a type we know...
        }
    }

    ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set everything up as FileTransfer and NOT TextTransfer?
It's possible that if you perform DND from one of the Eclipse views such as PackageExplorer or ProjectExplorer the trasfer might be a StructuredSelection. Therefore consider the 2 code snippets below>:

for Files:

```
if (getCurrentEvent().data instanceof String[]) {
   insertFileNamesFromStringArray(filesList, (String[]) getCurrentEvent().data);
}
```

For structured selection:

```
if (getCurrentEvent().data instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
   Object[] array = ((IStructuredSelection)getCurrentEvent().data).toArray();
   for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[j] instanceof IFile) {
        IFile dropFile = (IFile)array[j];
        filesList.add(dropFile.getLocation().toOSString());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: everything is set up as FileTransfer. I also debugged and discovered that getCurrentEvent().data is null at the point where I need it :-(